# Expo native runtime is not available: something went wrong and we aren't sure what it was

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error while compiling my code. I can only see a white screen in my app.
I am new to react-native, your efforts would be appreciated.

**My App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (<Text>Hello, I am your cat!</Text>);

};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^5.0.1",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: if you are new to react native i will suggest you to use older react native version around "0.63.3" and react": "16.13.1" as latest react native command installing expo into it which is causing issues

Comment: Did you try stopping the server and running again using npx react-native run-android